# How to change my state in my reducer, trying to set a property to true/false

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

My reducers are split, and in one of them my initial state and reducer looks like:

```
import Constants from '../constants';

const initialState = {
  fetching: true,
};

const boards = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case Constants.BOARDS_FETCHING:
      return state;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default boards;
```

How can I change the fetching property to true in the BOARDS_FETCHING case?

Update

My .babelrc looks like:

```
{
  "presets": ["react", "es2015"],
  "env": {
    "development": {
      "presets": ["react-hmre"]
    }
  }
}
```

Error:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to install `transform-object-rest-spread`

```
 "plugins": ["transform-object-rest-spread"]
```

For more, please check [`babeljs-plugins#transform-object-rest-spread`](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-object-rest-spread/)

Comment: is that covered in state-0? or a more comprensive one?

Comment: @Blankman preset-stage-0/ does not include spread operator plugins. check here https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-stage-0/

Comment: You should not mutate the state - use object.assign like this
 return object.assign({},...state, fetching: true);

Answer (score 0):

You should set it in the `case Constants.BOARDS_FETCHING` clause:

```
import Constants from '../constants';

const initialState = {
  fetching: true,
};

const boards = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case Constants.BOARDS_FETCHING:
      return {...state, fetching: true};
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default boards;
```

Comment: That is what I tried, but I get an error ```ERROR in ./src/reducers/boards.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (15:14)```   It doesn't seem to like the ... maybe?

Comment: looks like the spread operator (es6) is not accepted. The problem might come from your build config. Are you able to use this syntax anywhere else ?

Comment: @RIYAJKHAN added screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
const boards = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case Constants.BOARDS_FETCHING:
      return state;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

to:

```
const boards = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case Constants.BOARDS_FETCHING:
      return Object.assign({},state,action.fetching);
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Comment: Am I really mutating state the other way?